# Other programmers programming perspective

Tags: discussion

Just spitballing here but I just spent all morning trawling for StackOverflow questions to answer instead of writing a piece of code I have been postponing since yesterday.

My problem is its more satisfying to look at a problem some one else has carefully boiled down to the essentials [OK that parts a bit optimistic] and get the solution in a flash of insperation, meanwhile my own code is blocked in my head in a quagmire of real and imagined constraints based on where the code is going.

So how about somewhere on the Stack or elsewhere that we can boil up those code problems that aren't actually technically difficult but are just in need of a fresh perspective?

*Does this fit into the Code Review beta sites mandate?*

Comment: Are you referring to [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: In the last question I was

Comment: Isn't the answer to boil it down and then ask about it on stack overflow?

Comment: But after boiling it down it would still be a request for an opinion i.e. which algorithm should I go with?

Comment: You could ask on an IRC channel devoted to your programming language or framework and use pastebin or something else (like jsfiddle) to show your code. Some people still use IRC you know!

Answer (score 7):

No, this wouldn't be a good use of Code Review, as per their FAQ*:

> #### I'm confused! What questions are on-topic for this site?
>
> Simply ask yourself the following questions. To be on-topic the answer must be yes to all questions:
>
> - Does my question contain code? (Please include the code in the question, not a link to it)
> - Did I write that code?
> - Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?
> - Do I want the code to be good code, (i.e. not code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar)
> - **To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?**
> - Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?
>
> If you answered yes to all the above questions, your question is on-topic for Code Review.

I'm pretty sure that you can't answer yes to *does the code work* - and the question would therefore be off-topic.

---

<sup>* on-topic-help-center-page, whatever. FAQ sounds better.</sup>

Comment: since this is a discussion question, it's not appropriate for me to award an actual answer and alas my lack of cred on meta says I can't vote up the answer... but thank you for the response